# I am confused about PE file relocations

Tags: winapi, portable-executable

Wikipedia says this about relocations:

> PE files normally do not contain position-independent code. Instead
> they are compiled to a preferred base address, and all addresses
> emitted by the compiler/linker are fixed ahead of time. If a PE file
> cannot be loaded at its preferred address (because it's already taken
> by something else), the operating system will rebase it. This involves
> recalculating every absolute address and modifying the code to use the
> new values. The loader does this by comparing the preferred and actual
> load addresses, and calculating a delta value. This is then added to
> the preferred address to come up with the new address of the memory
> location. Base relocations are stored in a list and added, as needed,
> to an existing memory location.

I am confused as to why there would be anything else at `0x00400000` (default preferred base address) besides the base address for the process. It is my understanding that in virtual memory, the process has the view of an empty memory space in which it is the only thing that exists. With this in mind, how would anything be there before the process itself initially?

Comment: It matters to DLLs, a DLL is also a PE file.  The days that an EXE is loaded at 0x00400000 are about over [as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, in most cases, when a process starts there is no issue regarding the preferred base address! In some situations like "Process Hollowing" (a technique where an application replaces another one in memory), the preferred base address is an important issue that must be handled. See following link for more (low-level) technical details about this issue related to the preferred address.

[Introduction to Process Hollowing](https://www.autosectools.com/Process-Hollowing.pdf)

Comment: Yes, this is what I am confused about. I don't believe the processes would share memory spaces, so wouldn't 0x00400000 always be available to the process in its view of memory? Does ASLR make the spawning of processes on their preferred base addresses unlikely?

Comment: Yes, because of ASLR, one cannot rely anymore that a process will be started at its preferred base address.

Comment: I have implemented the code provided in the link you gave me. Whenever I run it, it says that the source base is at `0000000000400000` consistently, but then says the destination base is `00007FF68CE20000`. Could you explain why I would get this output?